# Parsing text file in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I have a text file that contains one line. Something like this: A10102012MikeM. The first letter can be either A or P, following numbers correspond to date, next comes name, and then gender(M or F). What is the best method to parse this info into Map ? Of course i can take string.substring(x,y) of each element. But it seems too hard-coded. Can this be accomplished with regex somehow??

Comment: Is it always going to strictly follow that format (A|P)DDMMYYY<Name>(M|F)?

Comment: yes, but name length can vary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this regex `^(A|P)(\d+)(\w+?)(M|F)$`.This will work but some conditions:

1) It will not check date validity.

2) Output should be exactly as you described otherwise it may fail.

```
String str = "A10102012MikeM";

String p = "^([A|P])(\\d+)(\\w+?)(M|F)$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(p);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()){
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
}
```

output =

> A 10102012 Mike M

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Java has very good support for regexes. You will want to check out [java.util.regex.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Pay special attention to the Matcher groups which will let you extract data from the regex matches.

Answer (score 1):

`^(A|P)([0-9]){10}(.+)(M|F)$`

- Group 1 ... A or P
- Group 2 ... 10 digit date
- Group 3 ... The name
- Group 4 ... M or F (gender)

Answer (score 1):

```
^([AP])(\d+)([A-Za-z]+?)([MF])$
```

this regex (escaping is not done) catches different part of data into groups, so that you could get them easier.

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative to regex, depending on your exact situation, may be the [flatworm](https://sourceforge.net/projects/flatworm/) project on sourceforge.  For example, it can read the text file and populate java objects for you.

They've got a good [field guide](http://flatworm.sourceforge.net/) that walks through a number of use cases.